# How can I write a method to build a query both for SQL and an array?

Tags: sql, linq, object

I have a method `BuildQuery` that dynamically generates a query. It works well for SQL:

```
    static MyType[] GetDataFromDB(MyDataContext db, string city, string district, string region, string country, string zip)
    {
        var q = BuildQuery(db.MyTable.AsQueryable(), city, district, region, country, zip);
        return q.ToArray();
    }

    private static IQueryable<MyType> BuildQuery(IQueryable<MyType> q, string city, string district, string region, string country, string zip)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
            q = q.Where(p => p.City.Contains(city));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(district))
            q = q.Where(p => p.District.Contains(district));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip))
            q = q.Where(p => p.Zip == zip);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(region))
            q = q.Where(p => p.Region.Contains(region));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
            q = q.Where(p => p.Country == country);
        return q;
    }
```

(Actually, this query is a bit more compicated.) This works well building an SQL query with some `LIKE`.
Now I would like to use the same query for an array of `MyType`:

```
    MyType[] SelectFromResult(MyType[] loc, string city, string district, string region, string country, string zip)
    {
        var q = BuildQuery(loc, city, district, region, country, zip);
        return q.ToArray();
    }
```

Of coarse this does not compile because `MyType[]` is an `IEnumerable<MyType>`, not an `IQueryable<MyType>`. Changing the type of the first argument in `BuildQuery` to `IEnumerable<MyType>`, compiles and works for arrays but won't build the SQL query.

I guess I could make BuildQuery a generic method, but how? Any ideas?

Comment: If you pass in your array with `.AsQueryable()` does that work?

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things about LINQ is that you can concatenate (link) the functions after each other. This is possible because of the introduction of extension methods.

If you change your BuildQuery function slightly, you can use it as any LINQ function. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
 private static IQueryable<MyType> BuildQuery(this IQueryable<MyType> q, 
     string city, string district, string region, string country, string zip)
{
    ...
```

Note the word this before `IQueryable`. This allows you to put the first parameter of the method (the IQueryable) before the method call.

**Back to your question**

Any `IEnumerable<TSource>` can be transformed to an `IQueryable<TSource>` using `AsQueryable()`, so also a `TSource[]`

```
MyType[] loc = ...
IQueryable<MyType> myQueryable = loc.AsQueryable()
                                    .BuildQuery(city, district, ....);
```

Well maybe you should give it a proper name: how about ToQuery``?

To execute the query, do what you want to do with it: `ToList` / `ToArray` / Count / FirstOrDefault / ...

By the way, when creating LINQ like functions, it is usually better to return IEnumerable / IQueryable instead of List / Array / etc, unless you really know that your caller wants the complete sequence. It would be a waste if you would call `ToList()` and your caller only wants `FirstOrDefault()`